# R: A for loop in R to check if values are greater than equation

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

For some reason I cannot think through how I should return only the values that match a given if statement. I would like only the values in a matrix that are greater than a specific value.

```
 somefunction <- function(c,r,matrix){
 d <- sqrt((matrix-center[1])^2 + (matrix-center[2])^2)
      for (i in matrix) {
    if (d < r)
               ##only return these values less than r
```

any guidance will help, even a direction to another post.

Comment: How exactly do you want those values returned, and do you want duplicates? For example, do you want them returned as a list or as another matrix?

Comment: As a list would be preferred. for instance: a=2,b=3,c=6 I would want to see a b c or 2 3 6

Comment: Try the solution I've posted below, and see if that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Create a vector of `NAs` equal to the number of entries in the matrix

```
temp = cbind(1:2,5:6)
temp_na = rep(NA, length(temp))
```

Find the entries which satisfy your condition:

```
good_entries = temp[which(temp^2 - temp >0)]
```

Embed these entries in your `temp_na` vector:

```
temp_na[which(temp^2 - temp >0)] = good_entries
```

Finally, return a matrix from `temp_na`:

```
matrix_good_values = matrix(temp_na, nrows = nrow(temp))
```

This matrix has non-NA entries satisfying any condition you wish to satisfy.

In your particular question, apply the steps to the matrix `d`.

Comment: How would i apply this to matrix d, within the loop?

Comment: Alex, I don't understand this logic well enough to manipulate it for usage. Possibly I can explain further.... I have drawn a circle, I have a matrix of points that must be within the circle. I need to return only those points within the circle when I call on the function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't understand your loop very well; what is this meant to do: `for (i in matrix){ if (d<r)}`? I interpreted your example as best as I could. Let's have a look at the answer by @merlin2011 which you said was helpful: in his loop, `i` is not explicitly used in any calculation. It is implicitly used when the matrix operation is calculated, but my solution let's you calculate this operation and consider the condition you want to satisfy without looping through the entries of the matrix.

Comment: i.e.: without using a loop, calculate `d <- sqrt((matrix-center[1])^2 + (matrix-center[2])^2)`. Then run the matrix `d` in place of `temp` in my example, changing the condition in `which(...)`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to just do the calculation on each element within the vector. It was the long way but it worked for the single stimulation I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you want something like this?

```
somefunction <- function(center,r,matrix){
retVal = c()
for (i in matrix) {
    d <- sqrt((matrix-center[1])^2 + (matrix-center[2])^2)

    if (d < r) {
     retVal = c(retVal,i);
    }
 }    
 return(retVal);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect guidance to what I am trying to get to!